# ImageMagick: convert image to B&W, high contrast!

Tags: graphics, imagemagick

I'm trying to OCR certain images, but am having problems with the accuracy. I would like to see if I can improve accuracy by converting images to B&W, high contrast. Any ideas how I can do that with ImageMagick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fred's two colour threshold ImageMagick script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/2colorthresh/index.php) might help.

Comment: Worked wonders! Any sharpening techniques you know that might further help my OCR efforts?

Comment: Well -- Fred has a range of scripts including a sharpener: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/sharp/index.ph (his sharpedge script might even be more useful for you). It's a page worth bookmarking ...